# Should total percentage be shown as negative or 0 in case total marks are negative?

Tags: reports

I have an application which shows total marks and percentage scored by the student in a paper. All questions are multiple choice questions, so to avoid guessing by students negative marks for wrong answer are put in place

Also there are graphs that show in each section of the paper, the marks and percentage scored by the student.

So my doubt is in case the student scores negative marks (overall score is negative or negative marks in a particualr section), should I show the percentage as negative or show it as 0.

Ex: Candidate score and percentages ->

> Section 1 ->  4/10, 40%
>
> Section 2 -> -5/10, **<-50% or 0% ?>**
>
> Total -> -1/20, **<-5% or 0% ?>**

Comment: The concept of "negative mark" is a bit confusing. If someone doesn't answer or say anything, he or she gets a zero, right? How can someone then get less than zero?

Comment: Actually it's a multiple choice question, so to discourage guessing negative marks are put in place. So for a given multiple choice question, correct answer fetches +3 marks whereas a wrong ans to it results in -1.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Is there a need for the percentage at all? It seems like 4 out of 10, or -5 out of 10 already convey the same information more clearly.

Comment: Yes but the total score might not be 10 or multiples of it in many cases. Sometimes it is 12/45 or 36/58, etc. Thats why percentages are required as they are easier to grasp. But not sure how to show percentages in case of negative marks

Comment: Percentage usually implies a "total" reference, so negative percentages probably only work as a subtraction from an 100% total. What if you shift the whole thing into the positive realm? Establish that students start at 100%, wrong answers deduct from this and right answers increase this, so, in practice, 100% = 0, 200% = highest mark, 0% = lowest mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question reminded me of my college studies many years back our lecturer do have negative marking system, it was +2 for correct answers and -1 for wrong answers. There was no negative percentage the lowest was just zero and I thought zero percentage made sense rather than having a negative percentage on the score.

While we did not have different sections but I noticed you have an example with different sections. Assuming that the questions are grouped into sections because they cover different topics, it would be unfair to penalise the candidate  on the section that they have scored well with negative scores from another section. Thus, if I were you I would present the scores as follows:

Section 1: 4/10 (40%)
Section 2: -5/10 (0%)
Total: 4/20 (20%)

Just sharing my thoughts.

Comment: Yup, makes sense. Thanks!